# InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException while trying to execute sql statement in springboot

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to execute below query to fetch server name in springboot.

```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT role FROM sys.geo_replication_links")
    public int getServerName();
```

I get below exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at datadog.trace.instrumentation.springdata.RepositoryInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryInterceptor.java:41)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy266.getServerName(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy237.getServerName(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'sys.geo_replication_links'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:602)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7418)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3274)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:247)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:222)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:446)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
```

I am not sure why I am getting Invalid object name for `sys.geo_replication_links`. I executed the query in SQL browser and it works fine. I am not sure if it is because of the entity which I am passing. I added this method in one of the existing

```
public interface ReadRepository extends CrudRepository<<ReadEntity, String> 
{
    ReadEntity save(ReadEntity var1);
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT role FROM sys.geo_replication_links")
    public int getServerName();
}
```

Is it because of wrong usage of entity?

Comment: are you sure that the return type of the method is int?

Comment: I am executing this from the application database but sys.geo_replication_links is in master database.  I tried this code but it didnt work ... @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT partner_server FROM [master].sys.geo_replication_links")
   public String getServerName();

Comment: Have you tried executing the native SQL in Sql Server ? If yes, does it work ?

Comment: yes, It works !!! The only difference is, sys.geo_replication_links is available in master database and in my application is configured to use application database.

Comment: @SajitGangadharan, you must use the master database context to execute the query, not the application database. Specify `master` in the connection string for this query.

Comment: yes, you are right. Do I need to create a new connection for master altogether or Is it possible to do something like this ?  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT role FROM [master].sys.geo_replication_links")  but it didnt work

Comment: @SajitGangadharan, I elaborated with an answer.

Comment: Depending on how you create the connection you might need to either edit it (to connect to master and then specify each time you want to use a table from your custom schema) or leave the connection with the custom schema in place, and create a second one with master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.geo_replication_links` is only available in the Azure SQL Database master database context. Specify the master database in the connection string (include `databaseName=master` in JDBC connection string) and use a 2-part name (`sys.geo_replication_links`) in your query to reference this system table. Use a separate connection string for your normal application database access (`databaseName=YourDatabase`);

Note that 3-part names in Azure SQL Database may only reference the current database or `tempdb`. Your query ***cannot use a 3-part name*** because the table exists only in master.

Comment: I get the message: Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.geo_replication_links' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: @SajitGangadharan, I reworded my answer to make it clearer why you cannot use `master.sys.geo_replication_links` and how to query the table.